# Symfony 1.4 Checking form values against database entries before saving

Tags: database, validation, forms, symfony1, doctrine

I am working with Symfony 1.4 and Doctrine.
I have a form that has six fields: name, parent1, parent2, parent3, parent4, parent5
Once the form is submitted I want to check the database for two things:
1. The name field is unique
2. That the combination of parent1, parent2, parent3, parent4, and parent5 is not already in the database. These values are all integers (primary keys from a related table), some fields are left blank as 0. They are going into the database based on the order in which the user inputs it, so I do not care about the order, but would like to make sure the combination itself does not exist before the form saves.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a sfValidatorCallback.  In your form class, add the following in the setup() function:

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'YOURCALLBACKFUNCTIONNAME'))));
```

Then, you can create this in the same file, the call back function:

```
public function YOURCALLBACKFUNCTIONNAME($validator, $values) {
   //Validate form here
   //Access form items using  $values['FORMNAME'];
   //$error = new sfValidatorError($validator, 'A Error Message.');
   //$es = new sfValidatorErrorSchema($validator, array('FORMITEM' => $error);
   //throw $es;
   }
```

Comment: Wow - I've been working on this for days! Thanks so much Jon, it's up and running!

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a Doctrine validator specifically for this, sfValidatorDoctrineUnique. In your form, try:

```
public function configure()
{
  parent::configure();
  $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array(
      'model' => 'MyModelName',
      'column' => array('name')
  )));
  $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorDoctrineUnique(array(
      'model' => 'MyModelName',
      'column' => array('parent1', 'parent2', 'parent3', 'parent4', 'parent5')
  )));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy - works great for the name, but it doesn't throw an error for the parent columns - even if I put it in the exact same order, it duplicates the db entry.

Comment: I suggest looking at the query it's generating and examining what's going wrong. It's almost certainly not an issue with the validator.

Answer (score 0):

**I know that your question is about doctrine but for those who is looking for this answer and use Proepl, there is Propel validator for this:**

Another useful Model-related validator is the sfValidatorPropelUnique validator, which checks that a new value entered via a form doesn't conflict with an existing value in a database column with a unique index. For instance, two users cannot have the same login, so when editing a User object with a form, you must add a sfValidatorPropelUnique validator on this column:

> // Propel unique validator    $form->setValidator('nickname', new
>   sfValidatorPropelUnique( array(   'model'  => 'User',    'column' =>
>   'login' )));